# How would someone move the active links content to position top.. by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

problem is, it automatically scrolls to the end of the page. the only things by default that should be scrolled down is the container - section 3.

https://codepen.io/jimjamjom/full/NdwoZZ/

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var target = $("#section3");
    $('panel').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100 }, 700);  
  window.location.hash = "#" + "section3";
});
  </script>
```

i have also tried:

```
$('.container').scrollTop($('.content').find('.active').position().top );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the Browser address hash to #section3.

```
window.location.hash = "#" + "section3";
```

By default the browser will change the scrollTop value of the page to the top value of this `id`.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ocoeabmy/1/) without the hash change.

Comment: @topazt If you would like to keep the hash change you could force a body scrollTop = 0. You will need a small timeout. However, it creates a strange effect. [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ocoeabmy/2/).